# How to connect juce graphic with different cpp program

Tags: c++, pipeline, juce

I am working on a program(cpp) and I wanted to add visual graph to represent the data I got from my program, so I created a program in JUCE for the graph. The problem is that I am not very familiar with JUCE and I don't know how to connect the 2 programs.

I thought about adding my original program to the JUCE part, but I don't know where I can start the code. In the example code I got from JUCE there is a function "initialise" at "main.cpp", the problem is when I tried to run code(loop) through there it just didn't work(no errors, just didn't do anything). So how can I combine my graphics and program?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, what you would do is to create a new JUCE component and draw the graph with your data in its paint method. Then if/when you want to update it, call repaint() on your component. So I would suggest the following steps:

- Create a new JUCE component (a new cpp class inheriting : component)
- Override the paint method
- Draw the graph in you paint method with a reference to your data